# Как перевести этот тест из should-синтаксиса в expect-синтаксис?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Как подобрать эквивалент этому выражению из `Rspec test`?

```
its(:feed) do
  followed_user.microposts.each do |micropost|
     should include(micropost)
  end
end
```

Раньше я подбирал эквивалент, вместо:

```
its(:feed) { should include(newer_micropost) }
its(:feed) { should include(older_micropost) }
its(:feed) { should_not include(unfollowed_post) }
```

Писал:

```
it { expect(@user.feed).to include(newer_micropost) }
it { expect(@user.feed).to include(older_micropost) }
it { expect(@user.feed).not_to include(unfollowed_post) }
```

А сейчас не могу понять. Помогите решить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне не очень нравится такое решение, но похоже, что в мире RSpec принято использовать в этих случаях **splat** (звёздочку, *расплющивающую* массив в список аргументов).

Простой пример для `irb`:

```
def f(a, b)
  a + b
end

args = [1, 2]

f(args)  # рухнет, вместо двух аргументов дали всего один
f(*args) # => 3
```

`include`-матчер принимает в аргументах всё, что должен отыскать. И либо найдёт все, либо тест упадёт. Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
expect(@user.feed).to include(*followed_user.microposts)
```

Под капотом там `to_a`, любой объект, у которого есть этот метод (в т. ч. `ActiveRecord::Relation`), будет таким синтаксисом обработан соответственно:

```
class Hi
  def to_a
    [:foo, :bar]
  end
end

def f(a, b)
  puts a, b
end

f(*Hi.new) # foo
           # bar
           # => nil
```

Но **не нравится** мне это потому, что **работает и в случаях, когда `to_a` нет!** "Расплющивание" и в этом случае выдаёт **массив** (гы-ы) из одного элемента.

```
f(*(Class.new).new)
#      ^ пустой класс
# !!! ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
```

---

Если считать `ActiveSupport` и его метод `in?` у `Object`, который делает `include?` наоборот (`a.include? b` <=> `b.in? a`), то можно сделать вот такой финт ушами:

```
expect(followed_user_microposts).to all be_in(@user.feed)
```

Читаемость однозначно выше, производительность скорее всего ниже, зато чуть выше надёжность: если `followed_user.microposts` нельзя будет перебрать, то звёздочка спокойно передаст в `include` один объект, а `all` грохнется, сказав, что получил не коллекцию.

- `all` проверяет совпадение с матчером всех элементов коллекции
- `be_in` это **динамический матчер** методом `in?`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)